# How to correctly use partition function with max function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as below, I want to extract only one record of every customer having data less than or equal to '06/30/2012' and the largest of the RowNum.

| RowNum | customer_ID | date | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 197 | BS:141723 | 6/30/2012 | 124693.08 |
| 195 | BS:165012 | 5/31/2012 | 26346.42 |
| 27 | BS:166289 | 6/30/2012 | 5253.67 |
| 41 | BS:209459 | 6/30/2012 | 32673.04 |
| 127 | BS:141723 | 6/30/2012 | 205849.11 |
| 15 | BS:192907 | 4/30/2012 | 106236.71 |
| 47 | BS:192907 | 5/31/2012 | 7430.6 |
| 97 | BS:165012 | 4/30/2012 | 721 |

The expected output should be:

| customer_ID | balance | RowNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BS:141723 | 124693.08 | 197 |
| BS:165012 | 26346.42 | 195 |
| BS:166289 | 5253.67 | 27 |
| BS:192907 | 7430.6 | 47 |
| BS:209459 | 32673.04 | 41 |

I have written this query

```
select DISTINCT customer_ID, balance
    , MAX(RowNum) over (PARTITION by customer_ID)
from Test
```

and the result which I am getting is below which is incorrect.

| customer_ID | balance | RowNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BS:141723 | 124693.08 | 197 |
| BS:141723 | 205849.11 | 197 |
| BS:165012 | 721 | 195 |
| BS:165012 | 26346.42 | 195 |
| BS:166289 | 5253.67 | 27 |
| BS:192907 | 7430.6 | 47 |
| BS:192907 | 106236.71 | 47 |
| BS:209459 | 32673.04 | 41 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group). If not, why does it not?

Comment: I am going through that as there are lot f answers for that,

Comment: @TarunSingh you can check the accepted answer first (answer with the green tick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
create table #temp(RowNum int, customer_ID varchar(32), [date] date, balance decimal(18,2))
insert into #temp(RowNum, customer_ID, [date], balance)
values   (197, 'BS:141723', '6/30/2012', 124693.08)
       , (195, 'BS:165012', '5/31/2012', 26346.42)
       , (27,  'BS:166289', '6/30/2012', 5253.67)
       , (41,  'BS:209459', '6/30/2012', 32673.04)
       , (127, 'BS:141723', '6/30/2012', 205849.11)
       , (15,  'BS:192907', '4/30/2012', 106236.71)
       , (47,  'BS:192907', '5/31/2012', 7430.6)
       , (97,  'BS:165012', '4/30/2012', 721)


select * from #temp

;with c0 as(
select customer_ID, balance, RowNum
       , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by customer_ID order by [date] desc) as rid
from #temp
where [date] <= CONVERT(date, '06/30/2012')
)
select customer_ID, balance, RowNum
from c0 where rid = 1

--OR

select customer_ID, balance, RowNum
from (select customer_ID, balance, RowNum
             , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by customer_ID order by [date] desc) as rid
      from #temp
      where [date] <= CONVERT(date, '06/30/2012')
) as dt
where rid = 1
```

Comment: Can we achieve this without using with clause?

Comment: ```select customer_ID, balance, RowNum
from (select customer_ID, balance, RowNum
             , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by customer_ID order by [date] desc) as rid
      from #temp
      where [date] <= CONVERT(date, '06/30/2012')
) as dt
where rid = 1```

Comment: I am able to get that working thanks.